# Using CallerMemberName attribute in a portable library

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone

I have a portable library that targets Windows Phone 7.1+ and Windows Store apps (for WinRT), which uses the .net 4.5 framework.

I would like to use the new `[CallerMemberName]` attribute in it. However, VS2012 told me that this attribute is not available in my portable library (that seems normal because it's not available in a WP7.1 project).

Yet, I have found out that I can create my own attribute and the compiler will understand it like the real one, by using this snippet:

```
namespace System.Runtime.CompilerServices
{
  [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter, Inherited = false)]
  public sealed class CallerMemberNameAttribute : Attribute { }
}
```

However, as soon as try to compile it, I get the error `The type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberNameAttribute' exists in both 'Portable.dll' and 'mscorlib.dll'`.

I understand the message, but I would like to know if there is a way to use `[CallerMemberName]` in my portable lib ? I might have missed something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [BCL Portability Pack](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl/) which provides these attributes for older versions.

> This packages enables projects targeting .NET Framework 4, Silverlight 4 and 5, and Windows Phone 7.5 (including any portable library combinations) to use new types from later versions of .NET including:
>
> - CallerMemberNameAttribute
> - CallerLineNumberAttribute
> - CallerFilePathAttribute
> - ...

Comment: I'd rather not use an external library (especially just for that). If they managed to do that, I guess that I can too. I'm unable to find the source, so I guess it's not an open source project... :/ Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Ashen: Well you can declare the attributes yourself - but then you'd need to consider all the aspects of type redirection. Microsoft has made this package available specifically to address this sort of thing. It feels like a pretty reasonable dependency to me...

Comment: Indeed. It adds task too, which is nice :)